# Issues displaying adsense in a ajax paginated view (cakephp)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, adsense

So far, whenever I set a script tag into a view, that is being shown inside other view with AJAX, this script isn't being execute at all. Any one knows a workaround for this? I'm brand new with AJAX and CakePHP.

Since Stackoverflow isn't allowing me to post my question I'm going to explain further my script issue.

I have my controller: `images`, that is showing lots of images, then i have my image's categories (controller: `categories`), which is showing all the different image's categories.

If you go ahead and pull categories' index view you will see that this guy is loading a div where images' paginated content appears (from images controller) and in between each image (from a page with pagination of 3 images each page) I have a script tag either from Google or smowtion, that is not being shown or being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely being caused by some Javascript not executing due to the population of content after page load, or restrictions from your advertising sources. Google's adsense program requires a specific access to enable use with ajax loaded content.